# Can Sanyasa be given to non-Hindus?

Tags: other-religions, sannyasa

https://openlibrary.org/works/OL1628976W/The_ochre_robe

> So that was young Leopold Fischer who landed in India with the sole desire of becoming a Sanyasi. (One has to be initiated into Sanyasashrama by one who is already a Sanyasi). But the monks in India could not accede to his request for grant of Sanyasa as they said it is the sole preserve of Hindus and he as an European is not entitled to follow Sanyasashrama. However, he luckily met one particular Sanyasi belonging to the Sringeri Sarada Peetam (One of the five Peetams established by Adi Sankaracharya) who was willing to initiate him into Sanyasa. Sitting right in the middle of two burning pyres on the banks of River Ganga at Banares (Varanasi) at midnight he was initiated into Sanyasashrama and Leopold Fischer officially became a Swami and his new name was Swami Agehananda Bharati.

Comment: To become a Sanyasi one should be a Brahmin and male.

Comment: Ramakrishna Mission has many non-Hindu sannyasis. You can see the photographs of 1 female sannyasi here: www.vedanta.org

Comment: But then they themselves (Ramakrishna mission) claimed they are not Hindu :-) (they lost that case in court) @Pradip Gangopadhyay

Comment: Their lawyers advised them to make use of the pro-minority laws to stop the CPI(M) government from taking over their shcools and colleges. The Left government wanted to boot out the Swamis and get CPI(M) goons to the governing bodies. The lawyers of RKM told them that as a Hindu org they will loose control over all their schools and colleges. Hence they tried to get the minority tag. After the fall of the left govt they have gotten the minority tag from the Mamata government. All this is to stop political interference and has nothing to do with their being non-Hindu.

Answer (score 4):

SanyAsa is not someone's monopoly and it is completely private. It is not dogmatic. It become dogmatic only when the SanyAsa is forced upon oneself by oneself.

> The Supreme Divine Personality said: **Giving up of actions motivated by desire is what the wise understand as sanyās**. Relinquishing the fruits of all actions is what the learned declare to be tyāg. BG-18.2

So anyone can be Sanyasi just by giving up actions motivated by desires. It has nothing to do with any establishment intrinsically.

Comment: Who uses supreme divine personality? Did the translator use it?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes, I also felt awkward while pasting here.

Comment: But this is not the external Sannyas. Where they are required to give up the thread and all. This is the internal Sannyas which is the real one. For the external Sannyas only Dvijas are qualified. @Rohit.

Comment: @Rickross internal is the meat.

Comment: If OP is asking about internal Sannyas then the question itself is invalid.. so answers should be given from the usual perspective..@Rohit.

Comment: @Rickross Then better you can answer. I am quite anti establishment in such matters.

Comment: Yes I can answer.. will see later.. the answer is obviously NO.. and if it's asking about internal renunciation then what's the need for asking for permission..@Rohit.

Comment: @Rickross Answer was needed to throw light on the fact that the internal Sanyasa is the the primary one.

Comment: In the Kularnava Tantram there is verse which says "for a Kaula Sannyasam is forbidden".. What do u think Sannyas means here? Internal or external?

Comment: @Rickross I will need to see context. ;)

Comment: @Rohit. There is no context. You won't be able to decide even if u read the whole chapter.

Comment: @Rickross It means external Sanyasa is forbidden then.

Comment: According to Mahanirvana though, a Varna Sankara can renounce. He will need to sacrifice just his crown tuft in the rituals. But this, Lord Shiva says, is not exactly Sannyasa but "Avadoota Grahana".. As per Mahanirvana this is the only kind of Sannyas allowed in Kali Yuga. @Rohit.